# If a triangle ABC remains always similar to a given triangle,and if the point B always move along a given straight line, find the locus of C.

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

If a triangle ABC remains always similar to a given triangle,and if the point A is fixed andB always move along  a given straight line, find the locus of C.

I have been able to solve it for a right angled triangle but not a normal one.How to do this?Solve using coordinate geometry.i have already done with geometrical proof.

Comment: Missing assumptions?  Please see my Comment on Beni's Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get from B to C you always have to make a rotation of angle $\pm\theta=\angle ABC$ around $A$ and a homothety of ratio $AC/AB$ of center $A$. Both these transformations map lines to lines, so if $B$ lies on a line, the locus of $C$ is also a line, which you can find by performing the above transformations.

If you don't want, you do not need to use geometric transformations. Consider $B, B'$ two positions for $B$ and the corresponding $C,C'$ Then you can prove that the triangles $ABB'$ and $ACC'$ are similar, and from there it is quite straight forward.

Comment: Perhaps you are assuming the point $A$ remains fixed?  And that the location of $C$ varies continuously with the location of $B$?  Such assumptions suffice to support your approach, but I didn't read these into the original Question.

Comment: @hardmath: If you don't fix $A$ then the problem is void. If $B$ varies on a line, $A$ can be everywhere, then $C$ can be everywhere. I'm sure that in the original question $A$ should be fixed.

Comment: My critique is more about the problem formulation than about your solution, but note continuity is also an issue (since we can at any time reflect $ABC$ across $AB$ and get another similar triangle).

Comment: @hardmath: Yeah, that's true.

Comment: ya A is fixed..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like $C$ can be anywhere in the plane. For every possible $B$ on the line and every $C$ anywhere, you can always draw the line $BC$ and find a place to put $A$ such that $ABC$ is similar to the given triangle.

Comment: Note: this answer was written before the condition that $A$ remains fixed was added to the question.